# ID2D1HwndRenderTarget::Resize FAILED

Tags: c++, direct2d

```
while( 1 ) {
    ...
    pdev->Resize( D2D1::SizeU( unclientwidth, unclientheight ) );
    pdev->Clear( &ImplColorD2D1( D2D1::ColorF(0.0, 0.0, 0.00) ) );
}
```

I want to update the size of the render target the same size with the window client size.

Code above is all my opertions where I call ID2D1HwndRenderTarget interface. Even there's no opertaion to render anything.

I tried to call ID2D1HwndRenderTarget::Resize but it returned the code below

```
D2DERR_OUTSTANDING_BITMAP_REFERENCES

0x88990022

The operation cannot complete while there are outstanding references to the target bitmap.
```

From MSDN

I tried to find what's going on for hours but it all come to nothing.

What happened in the world? Please reply me if you have any ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably you forgot to call `ID2D1DeviceContext::SetTarget(nullptr);` after drawing on this bitmap or something similar. You should add some relevant drawing / resizing code to question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply  Mr VTT, and I have added the code. But ID2D1HwndRenderTarget seems do not have a method called SetTarget.

Comment: That is because `SetTarget` is a method of `ID2D1DeviceContext`. Typical render sequence should look like `ID2D1DeviceContext::SetTarget`, `ID2D1RenderTarget::BeginDraw`, draw calls, `ID2D1RenderTarget::EndDraw`, `ID2D1DeviceContext::SetTarget(nullptr);`. `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget::Resize` should not appear in between those calls.

Comment: Thanks for a lot. I have solved the problem by removing the ID2D1RenderTarget::Flush Calling.